# multipart/form-data csv file upload POST PHP curl

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, post, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a file via http POST using PHP and curl.

I had no problems working with basic fields, however since I tried to upload the file, I still have no luck.

From the terminal I can easily get it to work with the following command:

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'auth-token: #.######.##.##########################' -F 'file=@test_csv.csv' -F 'command=import' -F 'parameters={"contact-list_code": "1", "separator": ",", "header": false, "file_columns": [{"Position":"0", "Field":"1", "Rule":"3"}, {"Position":"1", "Field":"14", "Rule":"3"} ] }' http://api.com/method
```

I tried using the following in php:

```
$file = '@'.realpath(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/exports/test_csv.csv');
$data = http_build_query(array(
    "command" => "import",
    "file" => $file,
    "parameters" =>  array(
         "contact-list_code" =>  "1",
         "separator" =>  ",",
         "header" =>  false,
         "file_columns" =>  array(
            array(
                "Position" => "0", 
                "Field" => "1", 
                "Rule" => "3"
            ),
            array(
                "Position" => "1", 
                "Field" => "14", 
                "Rule" => "3"
            )
        )
    )
));
$authToken = '#.######.##.##########################';

$serviceHandler = curl_init();
curl_setopt($serviceHandler, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.com/method');
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";
$headers[] = "Auth-Token: ".$authToken;

curl_setopt($serviceHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($serviceHandler, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($serviceHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($serviceHandler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($serviceHandler, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

print_r(json_decode(curl_exec($serviceHandler)));
```

Here's the error I received: `Error handling data from http request`

I also tried using `CURLFile` class for the file instead of the `@` for the file, however it gave me the same error.

I think it's worth mentioning that I'm running this code inside a Wordpress plugin.

I wonder what's going wrong with my php code since the curl shell command is fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `http_build_query` when constructing `$data` variable

From the documentation:

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix. As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile. The @ prefix can be disabled for safe passing of values beginning with @ by setting the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to TRUE.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However seems like I have to use http_build_query or json_encode because when I try without it, I receive an error saying the format is invalid.

Comment: What response do you get when you run it from the terminal?

Comment: When I run it from the terminal it just works as it should, the file gets uploaded and that's it, a success message. The issue is in my php code somewhere.

Comment: I mean if you run the php file from the terminal

Comment: Ohh, sorry, I misunderstood your question. The response I get is the same  when running from a web page: "Error handling data from http request"

Comment: Updated my answer, have you tried setting CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to TRUE.